# Remove properties in junit xml file before generating xml file in ant

Tags: xml, junit, ant, output

The junit xml file output is being generated using ant, It is including all the properties like system properties etc. Can we stop loading the properties in to xml file prior itself?

Please help and thank you.

Comment: May you can transform it later, right?

Comment: I have a requirement to exclude them junit xml report prior itself.

Comment: What is the core issue you are facing? I am afraid if that is possible.

Comment: I'm able to generate junit xml file, but it contains all the system properties like passwords, ssh keys etc.so need to stop including properties into xml output.
I know we can modify the xml output and remove the properties, But I don't know the output file location(If I apply it in a generic way to remove in all the .xml files then it is not appropriate).

Please suggest is it feasible?

Comment: You need to elaborate the question and include - how are you calling junit tests? using apache-ant? something else?